# Attach object to Arcore camera

Tags: android, object, android-fragments, camera, arcore

I'm trying to make an object which is attached to the camera and it's not an Anchor in android studio. It will move as the camera moves.
Here in code, I tried to save the position of the camera and store it in Vectore3, which is useless.
I found https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/103  which is done by the help of an identity matrix, but it's complicated. So, I need to know how to match the object and camera and how to update it.

```
                    Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
                    float x = frame.getCamera().getPose().qx();
                    float y = frame.getCamera().getPose().qy();
                    float z = frame.getCamera().getPose().qz();
                    Vector3 vec = new Vector3(x,y,z)

                Vector3 node = anchorNode.getWorldPosition();
                MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(getApplicationContext(), new Color(0, 255, 0))
                        .thenAccept(
                                material -> {
                                    ModelRenderable model2 = ShapeFactory.makeCube(
                                            new Vector3(.01f, .01f, 0.1f),
                                            zero(), material);
                                    nodeForLine2 = new Node();
                                    nodeForLine2.setParent(anchorNode);
                                    nodeForLine2.setRenderable(model2);
                                    nodeForLine2.setWorldPosition(?vec?);
                                    nodeForLine2.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), -40f));
                                }
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show an image of an object that must always be in the same place in the preview, like a viewfinder or a focus zone in the centre of the preview for example, then you may find it is easier to simply add it as a separate view on top of the AR View.

For example the layout below has a button overlaid over the AR Fragment, but you can replace it with a view containing your object or image for example.

```js
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="LineViewMainActivity">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/blank_button_bottom_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ux_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

If your requirements is for an actual 3D object that will look different as you move around it, i.e. you see the back of the object when viewing it from behind, you may find you have to reposition it at the centre of the camera for every frame, provided that does not prove to large an overhead for your application.

An example of code to place an anchor in front of the centre of the camera and attache a renderable object below:

```js
            // Place the anchor 1m in front of the camera. 
            Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
            Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
            Anchor newMarkAnchor = session.createAnchor(
                        frame.getCamera().getPose()
                                .compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0, 0, -1f)) //This will place the anchor 1M in front of the camera
                                .extractTranslation());
            AnchorNode addedAnchorNode = new AnchorNode(newMarkAnchor);
            addedAnchorNode.setRenderable(andyRenderable);                     addedAnchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
```

Comment: Exactly I need an actual 3D object which would be updated in each frame; the problem is finding the location of the camera and attaching it to the object in Arcore.

Comment: @Afshin - actually you might want to do it the other way round, re-attach the object to the centre of the camera each frame. First delete the old anchor and create a new one in front of the camera and then reattach the object. I've added some example code above

Comment: I add arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addOnUpdateListener(this::onUpdateFrame); 
in onCreate to update the frame 
public void onUpdateFrame(FrameTime frameTime) ,
but it always render my anchor reapitivly.

Comment: @Afshin- do you mean multiple objects are being added? You need to delete the original first. If you look at how the movement buttons work in this project you can see some working examples of deleting and replacing anchors and renderables: https://github.com/mickod/LineView

Comment: Yes, multiple objects are being added. probably it could be my answer. I will try... . Since I'm new user I can't vote for your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I faced this problem:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63356541/arcore-moving-the-object-which-is-attached-to-the-center-of-camera)